# Database Design using ER Model (Converting Multi-Valued attributes)

Tags: sqlite, database-design, entity-relationship, normalization

I have converted an E-R diagram into 3rd normalized tables, But i am not confident that i have done it right.

The E-R diagram and the 3rd normalized tables ( by me ) are given in the picture.

Please suggest me if this design is free of problems!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking fine,

for foreign keys, there is no need to add post fix "_fk", as it shorts the column name, if you are not using inno